# Специализация шаблонного класса с другим числом шаблонных параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть такой шаблонный класс c двумя параметрами:

```
template <class T1, class T2>
class A
{
public:

    void f()
    {
        t1 = t2.get();
    }

    T1 result() {return t1;}
private:
    T1 t1;
    T2 t2;
};
```

Есть ли возможность написать специализацию этого класса для одного параметра шаблона, что-то вроде такого:

```
template<class T1> 
class A<T1>
{

    void f() {/*do nothing*/}
    T1 result() {return t1;}

public:
    T1 t1;
};
```

но в таком виде это не работает, компилятор требует два аргумента.

Можно сделать так:

```
template<class T1> 
class A<T1, void>
{

    void f() {/*do nothing*/}
    T1 result() {return t1;}

public:
    T1 t1;
};
```

Но мне не нравится при использовании писать `void`:

```
A<int, void> a;
```

Хотелось бы писать просто

```
A<int> a;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

А вот [такой вариант](https://ideone.com/UcyskQ) не пройдет?

```
template <class T1, class T2 = void>
class A
{
public:
......

template<class T1> 
class A<T1, void>
{
public:
......
```

И вызываете

```
A<int> a;
A<int,int> b;
```